# Write undirected relationships/edges in Neo4j using Spark Connector

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, graph-databases

I am working with Neo4j to load my nodes and relationships into Neo4j using the Spark Connector.
Currently the relationships that I am creating has by default a direction, is there any method to write the relationships/edges without direction (undirected edges).

Code to load the directed relationship using spark connector:

```
df.format('org.neo4j.spark.DataSource')
 .mode('overwrite')
 .option('relationship', 'CONTAINS')
 .option('relationship.save.strategy', 'keys')
 .option('relationship.source.labels', ':Product')
 .option('relationship.source.save.mode', 'Match')
 .option('relationship.source.node.keys', 'productID:id')
 .option('relationship.target.labels', ':Order')
 .option('relationship.target.save.mode', 'Match')
 .option('relationship.target.node.keys', 'orderID:id')
 .option('relationship.properties', 'quantity:quantityOrdered')
 .save())
```

This will create an edge from **Product** node to **Order** node.

`(Product) - [r:CONTAINS] -> (Order)`

Is there any method using **spark** or using **Cypher query** (after loading the edges) to create undirected relationships between 2 nodes.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Neo4j does not support undirected relationships.
Though you can omit the direction during queries, e.g. `MATCH (NodeA)--(NodeB)` or `MATCH (NodeA)-[SOME_RELATION]-(NodeB)`, you really shouldn't, as it will decrease query performance.